# Where is the type of List declared in Elm?

Tags: elm

While some built-in types `Int Float Bool` are declared on [Baiscs module](https://github.com/elm/core/blob/1.0.0/src/Basics.elm), I couldn't find the declaration `List type` from [List module](https://github.com/elm/core/blob/1.0.0/src/List.elm) accordingly. How could the default `import List exposing (List)` even work?

Comment: It's a basic built-in type, so I don't think it's defined as a normal type in the runtime library at all

Answer (score 1):

The `List` type is built into the language itself. You can see the JavaScript source code in [`Elm/Kernel/List.js`](https://github.com/elm/core/blob/1.0.0/src/Elm/Kernel/List.js)